# Experiences of creating Social Network site in Django

Tags: python, django

I plan to sneak in some Python/Django to my workdays and a possible social network site project seems like a good possibility.

Django itself seems excellent, but I am skeptical about the quality of large amount of Django apps that seem to be available.

I would like to hear what kind of experiences you may have had with Django in creating social network type sites. Any experiences in using any of the Django powered social network "frameworks" would also be welcome.

Comment: "to my workdays" -- Disable VNC.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're interested in creating a social-network site in Django, you should definitely investigate [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/). This is a project that integrates a number of apps that are useful for creating this sort of site - friends, messaging, invitations, registration, etc. They're mostly very high quality.

Comment: I did some stuff on top o Pinax and had no problems with is. I second this suggestion, have a good look at pinax.

Answer (score -1):

Are you saying that a random survey of some posted Django apps (not Django itself) reveals that some people post code that doesn't meet your standards of quality?

Isn't that universally true of all code posted everywhere on the internet?

A random survey of any code in any language for any framework will turn up quality issues.

What's your *real* question?  Do you think this phenomena will somehow rub off on you and taint your code with their lack of quality?

Comment: Fine. The real question was: Web developers being second lowest quality developers, just above VB developers, I want to know if open source Django projects generally suck as much as, say, all Java projects?
:-)
But seriously, I just wanted to hear if there are particularly good or bad apps I should know about.

Comment: @Bloodboiler: Bad Django apps?  Bad social networking apps?  Bad social networking apps in Django?  What are you looking for?